# Deploying an SQS Consumer

Tags: amazon-sqs, task-queue

I am looking to run a service that will be consuming messages that are placed into an SQS queue. What is the best way to structure the consumer application?

One thought would be to create a bunch of threads or processes that run this:

```
def run(q, delete_on_error=False):
    while True:
        try:
            m = q.read(VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT, wait_time_seconds=MAX_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS)
            if m is not None:
                try:
                    process(m.id, m.get_body())
                except TransientError:
                    continue
                except Exception as ex:
                    log_exception(ex)
                    if not delete_on_error:
                        continue
                q.delete_message(m)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except socket.gaierror:
            continue
```

Am I missing anything else important? What other exceptions do I have to guard against in the queue read and delete calls? How do others run these consumers?

I did find [this project](https://github.com/zc/sqs), but it seems stalled and has some issues.

I am leaning toward separate processes rather than threads to avoid the the GIL. Is there some container process that can be used to launch and monitor these separate running processes?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things:

- The SQS API allows you to receive more than one message with a single API call (up to 10 messages, or up to 256k worth of messages, whichever limit is hit first). Taking advantage of this feature allows you to reduce costs, since you are charged per API call. It looks like you're using the boto library - have a look at `get_messages`.
- In your code right now, if processing a message fails due to a transient error, the message won't be able to be processed again until the visibility timeout expires. You might want to consider returning the message to the queue straight away. You can do this by calling `change_visibility` with `0` on that message. The message will then be available for processing straight away. (It might seem that if you do this then the visibility timeout will be permanently changed on that message - this is actually not the case. The AWS docs state that "the visibility timeout for the message the next time it is received reverts to the original timeout value". See [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html) for more information.)

If you're after an example of a robust SQS message consumer, you might want to check out [NServiceBus.AmazonSQS](https://github.com/ahofman/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS/blob/master/src/NServiceBus.AmazonSQS/SqsDequeueStrategy.cs) (of which I am the author). (C# - sorry, I couldn't find any python examples.)

Comment: In your implementation, is each of the Tasks calling `get_messages` or is there one Thread calling `get_messages` which then passes the messages to the worker Tasks?

Comment: Each Task is receiving and processing messages in a loop; there are no additional worker Tasks.

Comment: Won't that lead to situations where one `Task` reads 10 messages then must process them serially while other Tasks are sitting idle?

Comment: Yes - when configuring the maximum number of messages to read at a time, the tradeoff to consider is minimizing the dollar cost to AWS vs maximizing parallelism. Setting the value to 10 could potentially reduce your SQS bill by a factor of 10, but allows the possibility of reduced parallelism. Setting the value to 1 will maximize parallellism, but will increase the money you pay to Amazon.

Comment: Having said that, it's definitely possible to implement a single process that receives SQS messages and then queues them for other worker processes to pick up - but wouldn't this necessitate adding a second queueing technology (one to hold the messages received from SQS and awaiting processing from your other threads)? Doesn't feel right to add a queueing technology on top of another queueing technology.

Comment: Do you need another queue if the main thread/process polls SQS just for the capacity of open workers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71062/discussion-between-adrian-hofman-and-alex-rothberg).